# Overcome 8k limit to sql server stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql-server

I recently resolved an issue my VB6 application had when saving large binary objects to sql server using ADO 2.8 and the AppendChunck method for Recordset.Field.  If the data was too big I would get either 'Invalid Handle' in a for loop or 'Not enough system storage to perform this operation'.  I fixed the issue by sending chunks to a stored procedure and using 'updatetext'. However, in doing so I can now only send 8k characters at a time because of the 8k limit. Does anybody know of a good workaround?  Below is my sproc.

```
@chunck binary(8000),  
@result_id int

as

declare @pointer binary(16),  
        @imagelength int,  
        @datalength int  


--get the pointer and length to the image column    
select @pointer = textptr(result_image),  
       @imagelength = datalength(result_image)  
from dbo.dash_result  
where result_id = @result_id

if @pointer is null

update dbo.dash_result  
set result_image = @chunck  
where result_id = @result_id  

else

begin

  --append the chunck of data to the end  
  set @datalength = datalength(@chunck)  
  updatetext dbo.dash_result.result_image @pointer @imagelength 0 @chunck

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sql server 2000, declare the parameter as text. Note that it has to be a parameter and not a local var, only parameters can be text, not locals.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2005, you could use the varbinary(MAX) datatype or varchar(MAX) datatype, depending on the type of data you are storing.  I believe these can hold up to 2 Gig of data.